# what the model for logistic regression for repeated measurement?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, longitudinal

i have edit my code, by gather the period pre,mid,post into one column
my dataframe:  1-pre 2-mid 3-post

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
type<-c(1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2)  #is the factor level 1 and 2
k1<-c(30.7,20.3,3.4,22,11.6,29.5,15.4,2.7,2.1)
k2<-c(13.4,11,1.4,9.6,17.3,27.1,9.3,5.3,4.7)
k3<-c(1.2,10,4.7,2.6,13.4,14.8,8.8,0.7,4.6)
m1<-c(12    ,12.6,  1.6,    6.2,    10.5,   8.6,    15.3,   1.5,    1.3)
m2<-c(6.6   ,10.5,  0.5,    2.7,    5.2,    8.5,    9.6,    0.6,    4.3)
m3<-c(2,11, 2.6,0.4,7.2,9.4,12.3,0.3,2)
df<-data.frame(type,k1,k2,k3,m1,m2,m3,id)
df[,1]<-as.factor(df[,1])

dflong<-tidyr::gather(df,key=time, value=score, k1:k3,m1:m3)%>% arrange(id)

glm<-glm(type~score*time,family=binomial,data = dflong)
summary(glm)
```

the result:

> glm(formula = type ~ score * time, family = binomial, data = dflong)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-1.6828  -1.0472  -0.6594   1.1871   1.5688

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   1.44815    1.38283   1.047    0.295
score        -0.11494    0.08273  -1.389    0.165
timek2       -0.66855    1.91677  -0.349    0.727
timek3       -2.41924    1.83906  -1.315    0.188
timem1       -0.98737    1.86058  -0.531    0.596
timem2       -1.46293    1.84873  -0.791    0.429
timem3       -1.88813    1.73395  -1.089    0.276
score:timek2  0.01992    0.13972   0.143    0.887
score:timek3  0.22394    0.16556   1.353    0.176
score:timem1  0.02512    0.16115   0.156    0.876
score:timem2  0.07608    0.20938   0.363    0.716
score:timem3  0.15596    0.17164   0.909    0.364
```

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

```
Null deviance: 74.192  on 53  degrees of freedom
```

Residual deviance: 69.673  on 42  degrees of freedom
AIC: 93.673

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

the result look kind alright, i just want a second opinion on what i have done. it is alright to do this or not?

Comment: Your code for creating a data frame does not work. Check it again.

Comment: i have fix my data frame

Comment: It looks like you overparametrized your model. If you include only m's or only k's it works. If you include both you probably have complete separation. You need more data if you want to include all variables. Also, cbind in the formula doesn't do anything, you can't cluster variables.

Comment: You need a mixed effects model ...